# Error: /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.4 is not a valid keg

Tags: homebrew, gdal

I wanted to install package `gdal` on my Mac. I ran `arch -x86_64 brew install gdal`. However, it returned this error:
`Error: /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.4 is not a valid keg`

Comment: Seems the package is broken. Report an issue https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `brew update` before the `gdal` installation, the latest `xz` is [5.4.1](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/xz).

If still does not work, can you also update the OP and include `brew config` and `brew doctor` outputs?

Comment: "brew doctor" solved the problem - I had to clean up + delete the ceiling that was duplicated.